# Logs not being written by Forever or PM2

Tags: node.js, logging, forever, pm2

I'm trying to deploy a node.js app with logs being written to `/var/log/nodejs/myapp`.

I've tried [Forever](https://github.com/nodejitsu/forever) and [PM2](https://github.com/Unitech/PM2), but even though the log directory has the correct permissions and I'm passing the correct options (I think), the files are not created.

With Forever, I'm starting the app this way:

```
forever start ./app.js -l /var/log/nodejs/myapp/forever.log -o /var/log/nodejs/myapp/out.log -e /var/log/nodejs/myapp/err.log
```

After starting, if I run `forever logs`, I see that it is saving to the default `.forever/` directory.

With PM2 I used the respective log options as well, but nothing is being written. The `pm2 logs` command show me all the log info, but no file is created.

Any ideas?

Comment: First, the permissions of `/var/log` is `drwxrwxr-`, it means that only root can create file in this directory, if you want write to this directory, you must run forever by root. Then, you should confirm `/var/log/nodejs/myapp` is a exist directory, forever may not create directory by itself.

Comment: @jysperm hmm, I tried on another directory (/myserver) that is created by my user and has all the necessary permissions, still nothing. Even creating the log files before and running with sudo did nothing. thanks anyway

Comment: @jysperm oh, I tried with PM2 and it worked (on another directory). thanks, if you want to post as an answer I'll accept it. Not sure what's going on with Forever.